# Can't add user to sudo group

Tags: 20.04, sudo, adduser

I'm on AWS and despite being looged in as root, I can't edit `/etc/sudoers`

```
adduser houman
usermod -aG sudo houman
```

When I login as houman and try `sudo ls`:

`[sudo] password for houman:`

Any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sudoers configuration on AWS, but that appears to be the default sudo behavior. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Normal behavior. Being in the `sudo` group doesn't make you `root` all the time, it just lets you use `root`. Read `man sudo` and enter your user password.